# Query performance drops off a cliff with additional JOINs - can I fix this by adjusting a parameter?

Tags: mariadb

Running 10.8.8-MariaDB-log

I have a very complex query for a comparison site.

Essentially

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <tables>
                 JOIN <derived table 1 for first comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 2 for first comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 1 for second comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 2 for second comparison>
```

It runs in < 0.1s

If I change it to

```
SELECT <columns> FROM <tables>
                 JOIN <derived table 1 for first comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 2 for first comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 1 for second comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 2 for second comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 1 for third comparison>
                 JOIN <derived table 2 for third comparison>
```

It takes 10+ seconds

Indexes are solid, and the sql to create the derived tables is the same for each comparison, other than an ID parameter value.  All that changes is the number of them.

I suspect there's some buffer/cache that needs bumping up a bit? ‍♂️

**Yes**, I COULD rewrite the page/sql entirely to do it via a very different mechanism, but if I can fix this with a simple config change, then given the available resources on the machine, I'd prefer to do that.  Time is short.

I appreciate this may be an x/y problem, but I'm hoping there's an easy low-hanging fruit that the more experienced here will be able to identify immediately.

FWIW - shooting in the dark - I have tried quadrupling the size of these three, and it made no difference:

```
join_buffer_size      = 32M (to 128M)
sort_buffer_size      = 4M  (to 16M)
read_rnd_buffer_size  = 4M  (to 16M)
```

Thank you

Comment: We can't help you unless you give more info: the *full* query, the `EXPLAIN` plan, the full tables and index definitions. As a rule, there's no go-faster switch in SQL

Comment: Can't, or won't?  

Comment: Can't. There isn't a generalized solution to "make my query go fast". Each query has its specific issues and performance problems.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide GO FASTER suggestions.   We also NEED your EXPLAIN from your worst performing query.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Your bump ups likely caused the completion to be slower.  Even the numbers you started from contribute to taking more time than necessary. Our workload analysis will surprise you.

Comment: I actually disagree.  It can be great to see all of that stuff, and I've no doubt you would be able to point out COUNTLESS other issues with my schema/queries.  I am self-taught, after all...

But given the nature of the question ("this seems to be fine until I add more very-similar JOINs"), it pointed at a less-specific issue.  Something not wrong with my code per-se, but with the DB engine, or its config.

And I've just found it.  See my answer.

I THINK this is going to transform my life. 

Comment: I do welcome any words of caution about this approach.  But I'm normally pretty careful to write my queries in the order which probably makes the most sense from an execution point of view.  I'm not going to suddenly use `STRAIGHT_JOIN` everywhere, but I hope I do remember it whenever I have a "lot" (8 or more? ‍♂️) tables in a query.



Comment: This is an area where MariaDB's and MySQL's Optimizers have diverged.  Can you try MySQL?

Comment: I can't I'm afraid, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIL about `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

`STRAIGHT_JOIN` is like `JOIN` except it tells the query optimiser to run the query the way you've created it.

Why is this important?  Factorials, basically.

The optimizer knows lots of clever tricks to best-guess the best execution plan, but ESSENTIALLY, the complexity of working that execution plan, follows a factorial pattern.

- 1 table?  1 option
- 2 tables?  2 options
- 3 tables?  6 options
- 4 tables?  24 options
- 5 tables?  120 options

In the example in my original question, I had 14 tables.  87 billion options

And then 16 tables. 2 TRILLION options

Like I say, the optimizer isn't that dumb, it can prune a lot and take a lot of shortcuts, but I think the numbers do illustrate the issue with LOTS of tables in a query.  It's not how long the query takes to run that's the issue, it's how long the optimizer takes working out HOW to run it.

Case in point.  I've a query I've been testing/twiddling with in front of me right now, with 18 tables in it.

I did *literally nothing*, other than replace all my `JOIN`s with `STRAIGHT_JOIN`s.

**The result? My query time has dropped from 1.65s to *0.002s*.**

Answer (score 0):

This construct is terrible for performance because none of the "derived tables" have indexes:

```
FROM ( SELECT ... ) a
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) b  ON ...
...
```

So, yes, adding more `JOIN` is terrible for performance.

No, you cannot tune your way out of the problem.  (Tuning might help, but it is not a real solution.)

Let's see a more complete `SELECT`, together with some `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`; we may be able to provide some constructive suggestions.